# Google maps fully zoomed in all the time

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, visual-composer

I have a wordpress site with WP-bakery(visual composer) and have embedded a google map with an API key. Suddenly the map is fully zoomed in all the time. I try to change the scale in WP-bakery widget but it will not show right on homepage. Ex: www.admemo.net

Comment: You "have embedded a google map" - is this with the Google Maps [Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/), or the [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start)?

Comment: I assume you're following the instructions [here](https://kb.wpbakery.com/docs/wpbakery-page-builder-how-tos/how-to-insert-google-maps/) What does your embed code look like?  Add it to your question please.

Answer (score 0):

In your script you should be able to change the zoom value like so :

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   zoom: 15
});
```

Comment: I keep changing the zoom ratio in the WP-Bakery widget but it will not show it on the site. Where in the script shall I alter the number? What file?

Comment: I'd contact WP Bakery directly for support.

Comment: Where can I change the script? What file?